# UIImagePickerController and Interface Orientations

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app is universal.  iPad is landscape only (left or right); iPhone is portrait only.

Everything's working fine for iPhone as coded, but I'm getting the following error on iPad when attempting to present UIImagePickerController.

### Error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!'
```

Here's my setup...

### Info.plist (iPad Supported Orientations)

```
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

### App Delegate

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if(isPad()){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

### View Controller Presenting Picker

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if(isPad()){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
if(isPad()){
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}else{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

}

### UIImagePickerController Category

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if(isPad()){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    if(isPad()){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
}
```

### Worth Noting

The UIImagePicker (in iPad) is being presented from a view controller presented by a UIPopoverController

Answer (score 0):

In `UIImagePickerController` Category use

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {  
    if(isPad()){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not use a category to override a method.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you MUST present the UIImagePickerController in a popover on iPad.

Comment: This is only true if the image picker is not for the camera. For the camera, the image picker should be shown in a full screen modal view controller.

Answer (score 0):

The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. See [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)